# How to set bounds for only one parameter

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, bounds

I'm using curve_fit from scipy.optimize to fit my data. I have a function that fits three parameters (Z1, Z2, Z3). I wannt to provide bounds. However, I'd like to only provide a bound to Z2 (Z2 shall be below 40). I do not want to set bounds for Z1 and Z3. Is that possible?

```
            popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0 = [Z1, Z2, Z3],
                           bounds = ((10, 20, 5), (100, 50, 100,)))

            # This way I provide bounds to Z1, Z2 and Z3
            # I, however, only want to say that Z2 < 40
            # Also interesting would be to say Z2 < Z1, with no bounds for Z1 or Z3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I provide a pseudo-code solution that uses just remapping of parameters instead of actual boundary conditions

originally we would do something like:

```
bestA, bestB, bestC = fit( function( x, a, b, c, guesses=( guessA, guessB, guessC) ) )
```

However, we want the restriction that b < c. In such a case we fit the following instead (omitting the guesses)

```
wrapper_function( x, a, d, c ) = function( x, a, c - d**2, c )   
bestA, bestD, bestC = fit( wrapper_function( x, a, d, c ) )
```

like this the value `b` send to `function()` will always be less than `c`.
Assuming the fit converges we just calculate `b = c - d**2`. If we are also interested in the error of `b` we have to do error-propagation including correlation. ( see e.g. Joel Tellinghuisen, J. Phys. Chem. A 2001, 105, 3917-3921)

So `s_b**2 = gT V g`. where `V` is the variance-covariance matrix and  `g = df/du` and `u in [a, d, c]`. That is `gT=(0, -2 * bestD, 1 )`.

Now we want `b < min( c, 40 )`. That is, as mentioned in my comment, a bit more complicated, but also possible. We rewrite the wrapper function and have

```
wrapper_function( x, a, d, c ) = function( x, a, 0.5 * ( c + 40 - abs( c - 40 ) ) - d**2, c )   
bestA, bestD, bestC = fit( wrapper_function( x, a, d, c ) )
```

It might not be obvious that this does the trick, but if one plots `0.5 * ( c + 40 - abs( c - 40 ) )` it becomes clear. It is again straight forward to calculate `b`. For the error we have to be careful with calculating `g`, though. We get

```
g = ( 0, -2 * bestD, 1 - numpy.heaviside( bestC - 40, 0.5 ) )
```

Note: if the value and error of `c` are such that the discontinuity of the remapping is within error margins, this needs to be reconsidered, though.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) :

> bounds: 2-tuple of array_like, optional
>
> Lower and upper bounds on parameters. Defaults to no bounds. Each element of the tuple must be either an array with the length equal to
>   the number of parameters, or a scalar (in which case the bound is
>   taken to be the same for all parameters.) **Use np.inf with an
>   appropriate sign to disable bounds on all or some parameters.**

So you just need to provide `np.inf` as an upper bound and `-np.inf` as a lower bound for Z1 and Z3:

```py
import numpy as np
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0 = [Z1, Z2, Z3],
                           bounds = ((-np.inf, -np.inf, -np.inf), (np.inf, 40, np.inf)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What I don't get is how to to say Z2 < Z1, with no bounds for Z1 or Z3

Comment: @Alfred ...so...what is it: `Z2 < Z1` or `Z2 < 40` or `Z2 < min(Z1,40)`

Comment: @mikuszefski
sorry, I forgot to tag.
The middle one is fine. But I don't get how to implement the first and last one. Something like: 1) `(-np.inf, -np.inf. -np.inf), (np.inf, < Z1, np.inf))` and 3) `(-np.inf, -np.inf. -np.inf), (np.inf, 40 and < Z1, np.inf))`

Comment: @Alfred the first is easy to implement by changing the parameter in the fit function from `z2`to `z1- z4**2`. This is smaller than `z1` and you get the according `z2` via error propagation. Hence you do not need bounds at all. You can do this in a slightly more complex way to achieve the third version.

Comment: Third case could be done by `0.5 * ( z1 + 40 - abs( z1 - 40 ) ) - z4**2`. The `abs` is not the nicest on derivatives, but it should work

Comment: @mikuszefski thank you for your reply! I'm not entirely sure how to implement "changing the parameter in the fit function.." Don't I have to add z4 as a paramter to fit? Could you show me how the code would look like?
`p0 = `