# How can I bound an lmfit parameter based on another parameter such that param1 < 0.5*param2

Tags: python, constraints, curve-fitting, least-squares, lmfit

I have attempted to follow the example given in the [documentation](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/constraints.html#constraints-chapter) of `lmfit` and produced this:

```
...
params.add(name="m", value=m_init, min=m_min, max=m_max)
params.add(name="mni_minus_m", value=1, vary=True, min=1e-12)
params.add(name="m_ni", expr='0.5*m + mni_minus_m')  # max value of m_ni is 0.5*m
...
```

This resides in a function that takes args of `m_max`, `m_min`, etc.

As you can probably tell, I'm hoping for `m_ni` to have its maximum set as half the value of `m`, but otherwise being freely able to vary anywhere between zero (preferably minimum 0.1) and whatever the maximum is. Setting a `min=` in the intermediary parameter was suggested in a similar question for reasons of float precision(?)

Unfortunately, it seems this has actually just glued the value of `m_ni` to 50% of `m`. This seems to be the case for everything I try to fit with this.

It's entirely possible that this happened because that's just what least-squares has decided it wants to do and this is actually correct syntax, but I'm not sure and would like to verify with anyone more competent than myself.

I'm also wondering how I would set an initial value for `m_ni` in this scenario, as it's not exactly clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used this library but it sounds like you want

```
params.add(name="m", value=m_init, min=m_min, max=m_max)
params.add(name="mni_factor", min=0, max=0.5)
params.add(name="m_ni", expr='m * mni_factor')
```

or maybe the last one could be

```
params.add(name="m_ni", expr='m * mni_factor if m * mni_factor > 0.1 else 0.1')
```

to get your 0.1 lower bound, but I'm not sure if that's actually good for optimization behavior :)

Comment: You might be on to something here! I'll let you know if it helped soon, might get the same/similar result as I was getting before yet. It's being slow

Comment: i forgot to reply, anyway yes it worked! Turns out my actual model function is janky so it sometimes doesn't but this did work and allow it to move around!

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 or without bounds as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63580550/803359)